# Join on table retrieved from a previous join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

Any ideas how I can create a join on a table retrieved from data in a previously joined table? For example, I have an objects table that contains existing table Names, the display field of those tables, and the main ID field of those tables. I want to join on the table specified in the objects table as well as the objects table.

```
 select T.field1,T.field2,T.field3,O.DisplayName
 from tableT as T
 inner join objects as O on T.SystemObjectID = O.SystemObjectID
 inner join O.TableName as X on X.O.ID = T.SystemObjectRecordID
```

I understand the script above is not correct. But what is the easiest most efficient way of accomplishing this task? I hope I'm clear on what I'm asking...

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: To clarify you have a result set of 2 joined tables, and you want to treat that as a single table to join to a 3rd table?

Comment: @RayK - As far as I understand it, the OP needs the third table to be derived from a field in the sys.objects table. Using sys.objects as a kind of indirect lookup before joining on the dynamical identified table.

Comment: @RayK, Dems is correct. That's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Eric: Looks like you want a recursive CTE

Comment: @OMG Ponies: CTE? I'm not familiar

Comment: That query smells pretty awful.  Please consider consolidating all tables that could exist in the set of O.TableName into a single table.  They must have (at least some) overlapping schema, since they're part of the same query.  You may need an additional reference table, but it'll make that query so much nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

What you can do is take the results of that and create a string that is a SQL query.

You can even make that query parameterised and execute it using [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).
- That link has a few good examples to get you started.

This is because SQL is compiled to an execution plan before it is executed.  At this point in time it needs to know the tables, decides the indexes to use, etc.

This means that data is data and sql is sql.  You can't use late binding scripting tricks to modify the query that is already running.

You're stuck with SQL that writes SQL *(Dynamic SQL)* I'm afraid.

Comment: actually, though I didn't specify in the question I'm already using dynamic sql for the query. The tables can be variable and I just didn't want to join on tables now and have to come back later and update the SP by joining on more tables....

Comment: @Eric - Unless the table you want to join on is explictly stated somewhere in the SQL Query, you can't join on it.  You can use *tricks* such as making a view of `TableA UNION TableB`, etc, but then the fields need to match identically.  For a truely dynamic join, you need dynamic sql.